# A Lisp version of the Schwartzian transform

Tags: sorting, lisp, common-lisp

[Randal Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randal_L._Schwartz) stole Lisp's *decorate-sort-undecorate* idiom when he came up with what we'd later call the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). All of my Lisp knowledge disappeared through nine half lives, but I gave it a shot in [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/). I'm aiming for an idiomatic example I can use in a presentation about the history of the Schwartzian transform.

This works (and I know I can generalize it further), but I wonder how Lisp-y it is:

```
(require :sb-posix)
(defun schwartzian-files-mtime ( glob-pattern )
    (map
        'list
        #'cdr
        (stable-sort
            (map
                'list (
                    lambda (x) (
                        cons
                            (sb-posix:stat-mtime (sb-posix:stat x))
                            x
                        )
                    )
                (directory glob-pattern)
            )
            #'<
            :key
            #'car
        )
    )
)

(schwartzian-files-mtime "/etc/*")
```

Comment: Welcome to codereview! I hope you get some nice answers ! More, feel free to visit our [Perl section](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=unanswered&pageSize=15) and answer whatever question might look interesting for you

Comment: It's also not spelled LISP the same way that it's not spelled PERL.

Comment: @ferada LISP is LISt Processing. Perl is a name which is not an acronym. Often, LISP is capitalised as Lisp but I would posit that as wrong.

Comment: Which LISP? The original LISP? This looks kinda like Scheme but more like CL. Is it CL?  Which interpreter do i use to run it, and why isn't this confusing to anyone else? there are like, 10 different kinds of "real" LISP.

Comment: @cat `(map 'list ...)` is certainly CL. Have you missed the *I gave it a shot in [sbcl](http://www.sbcl.org/)* in the quesiton?

Comment: @WillNess well, maybe if it was capitalised and tagged properly...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What is not enough LISP-y in your function is the style used for the parentheses (they should not be left alone as last element of a line and they should be on the last line of the enclosed form). Another minor point is that you can use the shorter `mapcar` instead of `map 'list`.

Here is a version of your function (generalized for any function applied to the data and any predicate) which follows the more conventional style used in Common Lisp.

```
(defun schwartzian-transform (list costly-function predicate)
"sort a list of objects over the value of a function applied to them,
by applying the Schwartzian Transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)
the parameters are the list, the function, and the predicate for the sort." 
  (mapcar #'cdr
          (stable-sort (mapcar (lambda (x)
                                 (cons (funcall costly-function x) x))
                               list)
                       predicate
                       :key #'car)))

(require :sb-posix)
(schwartzian-transform
 (directory "/etc/*")
 (lambda (x) (sb-posix:stat-mtime (sb-posix:stat x)))
 #'<=)
```

Comment: No documentation string?

Comment: Nice transformation! The only thing I would change is to add space after lambda, although that's a small one.

Comment: @MatthewRock, thanks! Sometimes I miss that space.

Comment: Exactly like that! :)

Comment: isn't explicit `#'(lambda ...` considered a proper style?

Comment: @WillNess, in ANSI Common Lisp both forms are equivalent. In the [Google Common Lisp Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml)  both forms are allowed. I prefer the form without the `#'` since it is shorter but still very clear.

Comment: Yes I know they're equivalent, I had that impression about the style... Thanks for [the link](https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml?showone=__FUN_vs.__FUN#__FUN_vs.__FUN).

Answer (score 3):

What's certainly extremely *very* non-LISPy is your *opening* parens ending the line of code like that. With that, `mapcar` and explicit `#'` in front of `lambda`, it could look like

```
(defun schwartzian-files-mtime ( glob-pattern )
    (mapcar #'cdr
        (stable-sort
            (mapcar #'(lambda (x) 
                        (cons (sb-posix:stat-mtime (sb-posix:stat x))
                              x))
                    (directory glob-pattern))
            #'<
            :key #'car)))
```

This looks natural to me, but still may be off w.r.t. official style guidelines. It has a "quick-n-dirty" feel to it, like something you'd scribble on the spot (not unlike Randal's original piece of code), not a proper production code with documentation string etc..